# Dividing IP range among subnets

Tags: ip, subnet

A company has been allocated all the IP addresses in the range
134.7.1.XXX, and needs to create three (3) subnets. The first subnet needs to be
twice the size of the other 2

Is the answer simply:

```
Subnet 1: 134.7.1.000 - 134.7.1.499

Subnet 2: 134.7.1.500 - 134.7.1.749

Subnet 3: 134.7.1.750 - 134.7.1.999
```

Comment: This site isn't for your homework questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should go and re-read the wikipedia article for [subnetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). A basic grasp of [IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) will help you more with your homework than just copying answers off here.

You didn't explicitly state it in the question, but I'll assume you have a /24 network and want to divide it into one 1x /25 and 2x /26
So you end up with 134.7.1.0/25, 134.7.1.128/26 and 134.7.1.192/26

Comment: Please do not help people who are spewing their homework questions here without any bit of research on their own. Doing so does nothing but enable the type of brain-dead behavior that is already all-too present at SF and in Sysadmin in general.